# Append viewoport from JQuery in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change viewport on the go, without changing the orientation.
my current code works well on all browsers but safari,

```
$("#viewport").attr("content", "initial-scale=.25,minimum-scale=0.25,maximum-scale=.25,user-scalable= no");
```

Chrome act as soon as this function is triggered and make the browser window to default zoom, but safari is not changing the zoom, unless orientation changed.

Comment: Maybe UI needs a repaint

Comment: @A.Wolff can you please guide me how to repaint iphone safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IOS Safari dosen't support real time viewport change from JavaScript. You have to change orientation before viewport change event occur or use pinch zoom plugin to disable and enable zooming.